# glyphicons bootstrap icon not align with textarea

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

The glyphicons icon is hihger than textarea input.

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
    <label class="label-margin" for="name"><span class="label-required">* 
  </span>Message</label>
        <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i 
   class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left" ></i></span>
            <textarea class="message" cols="35" id="message" name="message" 
  rows="8"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `form-control` class to textarea like following

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
    <label class="label-margin" for="name"><span class="label-required">* 
  </span>Message</label>
        <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i 
   class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left" ></i></span>
            <textarea class="message form-control" cols="35" id="message" name="message" 
  rows="8"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Working fiddle

**[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/ocs69ss5/9/)**

Comment: it works. i missed the form-control. @Lokesh Gupta tq. but how about the select2 dropdown?

Comment: You can use same class or create a fiddle so i can understand better way

Comment: okay i will create. but one more i want to remove the label and just put the asterisk before the field

Comment: So use `col-md-4` in `form-group` and put the `asterisk ` in the div